Wakeup Hook on Apple Silicon
Mac Air M2 running Sonoma 14.5. Trying to schedule a wakeup from sleep and trigger a script. I can schedule the wakeup no problem using pmset -g schedule but the hook script is only executed if the lid is open. If the lid is closed the mac goes back to sleep after a few seconds without running the hook.
I have tried  both SleepWatcher and Shortery and the behaviour is the same. Anyone know of a way to achieve this?
